# Erro ao ler JSON gerado dinamicamente com file_get_contents

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tenho este código que me gera um arquivo json

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;"); 
$codigo = $_GET['cod']; //variável para parametro que será passado ao servidor via    
URL
$sql1 = mysql_query("Select nome, valor from produtos where id_produtos = '21' "); // 
comando SQL para buscar informações do banco de dados

$jsonObj= array(); // cria uma variável que receberá um array (JSON)
while($result=mysql_fetch_object($sql1))
{
$jsonObj[] = $result;
}

$final_res =json_encode($jsonObj); // "transforma" o array recebido em JSON
echo $final_res;
exit;
```

E que está me retornando este codigo

```
[{"nome":"SAO PAULO CENTRO X COPACABANA","valor":"200,00"}]
```

Só que esta me dando erro ao ler ele com o este codigo de leitura
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mrangelc/public_html/mpitech.com.br/transporte/teste/webler.php on line 13

```
$json = file_get_contents('webserv.php');
$lista = json_decode($json, true);
// Veja como fica o resultado
var_dump($lista);

// Manipulando o resultado como PHP.
foreach($lista as $objeto) {
print "nome: {$objeto['nome']} ,a valor: {$objeto['valor']}";
}

$objeto = json_decode($json);

echo 'Nome: ' . $objeto->nome;
echo 'valor: ' . $objeto->valor;
```

Oque deve estar errado?

Comment: Verifique o valor de `$lista` e de `$json` algum deles está errado.

Comment: Quando você dá um `file_get_contents('webserv.php')`, significa que você está pegando o conteúdo dele – exatamente um arquivo PHP. Substitua essa linha por `include('webserv.php')`, coloque o resultado da query em uma variável e use essa variável para gerar o JSON.

Comment: Tentei utilizar o include mais ai só repetiu o resultado do webserv.php

Comment: o valor dá variavel lista provavelmente não está vindo como um array, verifique por que

Comment: Acho que é quase o que o @RodrigoRigotti disse, mas um simples `include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulei o seu caso com o seguinte código:

```
$json = file_get_contents('arquivo.json');
$variable = json_decode($json);
foreach ($variable as $key) {
    echo "nome: " . $key->nome;
    echo "valor: " . $key->valor;
}
```

E com um arquivo.json:

```
[{"nome":"SAO PAULO CENTRO X COPACABANA","valor":"200,00"}]
```

Caso seu `var_dump` da variável já decodada (nesse exemplo é a `$variable`) seja a abaixo,  você deve conseguir o resultado seja acessado como um objeto da classe padrão do php `stdClass`.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(29) "SAO PAULO CENTRO X COPACABANA"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(6) "200,00"
    }
}
```

Sei que você usa o php para gerar dinamicamente seus valores, revise seu resultado também seria uma boa dica.

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o @RodrigoRigotti no comentário dele, fazer `file_get_contents` de um arquivo PHP traz seu código-fonte, e não o arquivo processado.

Segundo [esta resposta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5948451/825789) você tem duas opções para resolver isso:

1. Fazer o arquivo incluído retornar um valor (com `return`, não `echo`), e então incluí-lo assim:

   ```
   $json = include 'webserv.php';
   ```
2. Se não for possível alterar o arquivo para que retorne um valor, você precisa usar *output buffering*:

   ```
   ob_start();
   include 'webserv.php';
   $json = ob_get_clean();
   ```

   Também é possível criar uma função para isso, como na resposta aceita da pergunta em inglês. Altamente recomendado se você for usar esse tipo de coisa mais de uma vez.